# x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lc

Tags: r, linux, ld

I cannot install most of new packages in R, because of the following error:

> x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lc.

in some cases it is cannot find

> x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lm

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397191/usr-bin-x86-64-linux-gnu-ld-cannot-find), the -l option is for linking dynamic libraries. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980152/cs-software-anaconda3-compiler-compat-ld-cannot-find-lm-cannot-find-lpthread) suggests `sudo yum install glibc-static`. But, I have no administration permission.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: libc.so, libm.so : `cd /home/name/lib/ && ln -s /lib64/libc-2.17.so libc.so && ln -s /lib64/libm-2.17.so libm.so` ... Packages, e.g. glibc-static : http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.6.1810/updates/x86_64/Packages/ ← http://mirror.centos.org/centos/

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I linked /lib64/libc-2.12.so libc.so && ln -s /lib64/libm-2.12.so libm.so to a lib directory which is already defined in cshrc.

Comment: Well, then please try out `glibc-static` → EL6 → http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.10/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-static-2.12-1.212.el6_10.3.x86_64.rpm ← http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.10/ .... Unpack the downloaded rpm package https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3d9QqrRhEThYByPDgWEaoxHnqWFWqfE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I unpacked the package. now I have a directory /usr/lib64. Should I compile this package? because all files end to .a (not .so). Sorry I am a newbie in unix.

Comment: `usr/lib64/{libc.a, libc.m}` : Copy the two files to your preferred "lib/" directory. Build your application : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib-folder:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [other command]`

Comment: Now this error: "opt/anaconda/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld: /opt/local/lib/R/lib/libc.a(wordcopy.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC/"

Comment: Many thanks. I followed your first comment again. This time I added those files to /opt/local/lib/R/lib. Thanks again. You solved my problem that I was struggling with it within last three month. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to [Knud Larsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4491743/knud-larsen). 
I did

```
ln -s /lib64/libc-2.17.so /..../lib/R/lib/libc.so
```

and

```
ln -s /lib64/libm-2.17.so /...../lib/R/lib/libm.so
```

Now it works.